# python scipy.stats.powerlaw negative exponent

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, idl-programming-language

I want to supply a negative exponent for the scipy.stats.powerlaw routine, e.g. a=-1.5, in order to draw random samples:

```
"""
powerlaw.pdf(x, a) = a * x**(a-1)
"""

from scipy.stats import powerlaw
R = powerlaw.rvs(a, size=100)
```

Why is a > 0 required, how can I supply a negative a in order to generate the random samples, and how can I supply a normalization coefficient/transform, i.e.

```
PDF(x,C,a) = C * x**a
```

The documentation is here

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powerlaw.html

Thanks!

EDIT: I should add that I'm trying to replicate IDL's RANDOMP function:

http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/math/randomp.pro

Comment: What is 'a' here and how is it calculated? Didn't get from the scipy documentation @unutbu

Answer (score 6):

A PDF, integrated over its domain, must equal one. In other words, the area under a probability density function's curve must equal one.

```
In [36]: import scipy.integrate as integrate
In [40]: y, err = integrate.quad(lambda x: 0.5*x**(-0.5), 0, 1)

In [41]: y
Out[41]: 0.9999999999999998  # The integral is close to 1
```

The powerlaw density function has a domain from 0 <= x <= 1. On this domain, the integral of `x**b` is  finite for any `b` > -1. When `b` is smaller, `x**b` blows up too rapidly near `x = 0`. So it is not a valid probability density function when `b <= -1`.

```
In [38]: integrate.quad(lambda x: x**(-1), 0, 1)
UserWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved...
# The integral blows up
```

Thus for `x**(a-1)`, `a` must satisfy `a-1 > -1` or equivalently, `a > 0`.

The first constant `a` in `a * x**(a-1)` is the normalizing constant which makes the integral of `a * x**(a-1)` over the domain [0,1] equal to 1. So you don't get to choose this constant independent of `a`.

Now if you change the domain to be a measurable distance away from 0, then yes, you could define a PDF of the form `C * x**a` for negative `a`. But you'd have to state what domain you want, and I don't think there is (yet) a PDF available in `scipy.stats` for this.

Comment: To the last part: using a positive location `loc` we can shift the distribution. It would follow then from this explanation, that the restriction on `a` could be relaxed as a function of the location `loc`. Should be worth some testing and it should be possible to make the extension in scipy.stats.

Comment: @user333700: Although you could use `loc` to shift the distribution, the restriction `a > 0` would remain, since the shift is performed last, after the underlying distribution is generated.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about this correctly. It would need an extra shape parameter to shift and widen the support of the distribution.

Comment: I think this is not yet possible in scipy, but I really wonder why is so hard. This pdf has an analytic cumulative so it can be easily solved as pointed out by others with the method outlined in textbooks or [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomNumber.html)

Answer (score 6):

The Python package [powerlaw](https://github.com/jeffalstott/powerlaw) can do this. Consider for `a>1` a power law distribution with probability density function

```
f(x) = c * x^(-a)
```

for `x > x_min` and `f(x) = 0` otherwise. Here `c` is a normalization factor and is determined as

```
c = (a-1) * x_min^(a-1).
```

In the example below it is `a = 1.5` and `x_min = 1.0` and comparing the probability density function estimated from the random sample with the PDF from the expression above gives the expected result.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

import numpy as np
import powerlaw

a, xmin = 1.5, 1.0
N = 10000

# generates random variates of power law distribution
vrs = powerlaw.Power_Law(xmin=xmin, parameters=[a]).generate_random(N)

# plotting the PDF estimated from variates
bin_min, bin_max = np.min(vrs), np.max(vrs)
bins = 10**(np.linspace(np.log10(bin_min), np.log10(bin_max), 100))
counts, edges = np.histogram(vrs, bins, density=True)
centers = (edges[1:] + edges[:-1])/2.

# plotting the expected PDF 
xs = np.linspace(bin_min, bin_max, 100000)
pl.plot(xs, [(a-1)*xmin**(a-1)*x**(-a) for x in xs], color='red')
pl.plot(centers, counts, '.')

pl.xscale('log')
pl.yscale('log')

pl.savefig('powerlaw_variates.png')
```

returns

[image: power_law]

Answer (score 3):

If r is a uniform random deviate U(0,1), then x in the following expression is a power-law distributed random deviate:

```
x = xmin * (1-r) ** (-1/(alpha-1))
```

where xmin is the smallest (positive) value above which the power-law distribution holds, and alpha is the exponent of the distribution.

Comment: Why note just `x = xmin * (r) ** (-alpha)` ?

Comment: Don't know.  This is just the formula I got from Aaron Clauset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate power-law distribution, you can use a random deviation. You just have to generate a random number between [0,1] and apply the inverse method ([Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomNumber.html)). In this case, the probability density function is:

> p(k) = k^(-gamma)

and ***y*** is the variable uniform between 0 and 1.

> y ~ U(0,1)

```
import numpy as np

def power_law(k_min, k_max, y, gamma):
    return ((k_max**(-gamma+1) - k_min**(-gamma+1))*y  + k_min**(-gamma+1.0))**(1.0/(-gamma + 1.0))
```

Now to generate a distribution, you just have to create an array

```
nodes = 1000
scale_free_distribution = np.zeros(nodes, float)
k_min = 1.0
k_max = 100*k_min
gamma = 3.0

for n in range(nodes):
    scale_free_distribution[n] = power_law(k_min, k_max,np.random.uniform(0,1), gamma)
```

This will work to generate a power-law distribution with gamma=3.0, if you want to fix the average of distribution, you have to study [Complex Networks](http://barabasi.com/networksciencebook/chapter/4#scale-free) cause the k_min depends of k_max and the average connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is almost the same as Virgil's above, with the crucial difference that that alpha is actually the *negative* exponent of powerlaw distribution

So, if r is a uniform random deviate U(0,1), then x in the following expression is a power-law distributed random deviate:

```
x = xmin * (1-r) ** (-1/(alpha-1))
```

where xmin is the smallest (positive) value above which the power-law distribution holds, and alpha is the *negative* exponent of the distribution, that is the P(x) = [constant] * x**-alpha