# Python : generating random numbers from a power law distribution

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I want to draw a random variable between 2 to 15, from a power law distribution with negative exponent (a = -2). I found the following :

```
r = scipy.stats.powerlaw.rvs(a, loc = 2, scale = 13, size = 1000)
```

But it does not take negative numbers for a.

Anyone knows a way out?

Comment: Try (1/2) instead. Should effectively be the same thing.

Comment: Someone answered it right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882907/python-scipy-stats-powerlaw-negative-exponent - if you understand something from it.

Comment: @RobFoley, I need to check it for different negative exponents.. -1.5, -2, -3 etc.. hence i was hoping if i could get a more general advice :(

@Faflok I read that.. but it didn't help me get rid of the `a>0` condition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Power law distribution as defined in `numpy.random` and `scipy.stats` are not defined for negative `a` in the mathematical sense as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882907/python-scipy-stats-powerlaw-negative-exponent): they are not normalizable because of the singularity at zero. So, sadly, the math says 'no'.

You can define a distribution with pdf proportional to `x^{g-1}` with `g < 0` on an interval which does not contain zero, if that's what you are after.

For `pdf(x) = const * x**(g-1)` for `a <= x <= b`, the transformation from a uniform variate (`np.random.random`) is:

```
In [3]: def rndm(a, b, g, size=1):
    """Power-law gen for pdf(x)\propto x^{g-1} for a<=x<=b"""
   ...:     r = np.random.random(size=size)
   ...:     ag, bg = a**g, b**g
   ...:     return (ag + (bg - ag)*r)**(1./g)
```

Then you can do, for example,

```
In [4]: xx = rndm(1, 2, g=-2, size=10000)
```

and so on.

For completeness, here is pdf:

```
In [5]: def pdf(x, a, b, g):
    ag, bg = a**g, b**g
   ....:     return g * x**(g-1) / (bg - ag)
```

This all assumes that `a < b` and `g != 0`. These formulas should agree with `numpy.power` and `scipy.stats.powerlaw` for `a=0`, `b=1` and `g > 0`.